# Having troubles in cPanel with a redirect

Tags: redirect

I have created a subdomain on my website like such www.mysite.com/forum/

when someone goes to that link, I would like them to be redirected to www.forum.mysite.com

I have set a redirect up in cPanel, but it doesnt seem to redirect the folder. I have also tried setting it up under the sub domain and still not working, is there a htaccess code I can add ?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CPanel will add this to the .htaccess in your site's public_html root folder. Check if cPanel is creating what you mentioned, if not try this:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$  http://www.forum.mysite.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]